Error while filtering the DataFrame by column value in Rust with Polars: Expected &column, found &str
I’m working with a CSV file in Rust using the Polars library and successfully read the CSV into a DataFrame. Now, I need to filter the DataFrame based on a specific value in the "City" column.
Here’s the code I used to filter by the "City" column:
let filtered_df = df.filter(&df["City"].eq("California"))?;

I am getting the error:
error: arguments to the method `eq` are incorrect: expected `&column`, found `&str`

I’m unsure how to correctly filter the DataFrame by a string value ("California").
Could someone explain how to properly filter the DataFrame by the "City" column using Polars?
Thanks for your time and help.

To apply the filter, first, you need to create a mask.
let mask = df
        .column("City")
        .unwrap()
        .as_materialized_series()
        .equal("California")
        .unwrap();

This will return aChunkedArray of BooleanType types. You can then pass the reference of the mask to the filter function.
let filtered_df = df.filter(&mask);

Note: This is tested with the latest version of rust polars(0.44.2)
